# SQL: Reconcile quantity using same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

[image]

Trying to do a poor man's supply chain.
We get messages of the operation (R for Receive, S for Send).
Each location reports using their ID code (SRC), the quantity they send or receive, and the destination. If someone is sending, destination is where the goods are going, if it's receiving, the destination field is where the data came from.

The only location not having a destination is the HO (Head Office), cause it's the root node.

Now, I want to get a report of discrepancies. The last 2 transactions (ID 21 & 22) are missing 10 and 5 nets respectively.

I want to join the data so that the dest column matches the src column, and see the difference between QTYS and QTYR.

Example report:
[image]

But the SQL that I have written also provides some false positives?!?
[image]

My SQL code:

```
SELECT datas.SRC, datas.QTYR - datar.qtyS AS Difference 
FROM data as datas JOIN data as datar on datas.dest = datar.src 
WHERE datas.QTYR - datar.qtyS < 0 GROUP BY datas.src
```

The DB:

```
CREATE TABLE data (ID Int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, SRC NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, QTYR INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, QTYS INT NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0, DEST NVARCHAR(20), OP NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(ID));
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HO01",1500000,"","R");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HO02",1500000,"","R");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYS, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HO01",750000,"DO01","S");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYS, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HO01",750000,"DO02","S");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYS, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HO02",750000,"DO03","S");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYS, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HO02",750000,"DO04","S");

INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("DO01",750000,"HO01","R");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("DO02",750000,"HO01","R");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("DO03",750000,"HO02","R");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("DO04",750000,"HO02","R");

INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYS, DEST, OP) VALUES ("DO01",375000,"HC01","S");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYS, DEST, OP) VALUES ("DO02",375000,"HC02","S");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYS, DEST, OP) VALUES ("DO03",375000,"HC03","S");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYS, DEST, OP) VALUES ("DO04",375000,"HC04","S");

INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HC01",375000,"DO01","R");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HC02",375000,"DO02","R");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HC03",375000,"DO03","R");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HC04",375000,"DO04","R");

INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYS, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HC01",100000,"DP01","S");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYS, DEST, OP) VALUES ("HC01",100000,"DP02","S");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("DP01",99990,"HC01","R");
INSERT INTO DATA (SRC, QTYR, DEST, OP) VALUES ("DP02",99995,"HC01","R");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query solves your problem:

```
select *,
  qtyr-qtys as Diff
from (
  select SRC, sum(QTYR) as qtyr
  from data s
  group by SRC
  ) s
  join (
    select DEST, sum(QTYS) as qtys
    from data s
    group by DEST
    ) d
    ON s.SRC=d.DEST
where qtyr!=qtys
```

It just sums the amounts sent, the amounts received, grouped by sender/receiver, respectively, and then checks if the number matches.
Remark that you want to group by two different concepts, first by sender and then by receiver. This part could be the issue with your query.